# Configurable Product Missing Category

Tags: category, configurable-product

When clicking on a configurable product in the category view I'm redirected to a blank white page with the following error:

string(59) "http://www.smashingcases.co.uk/configurable-iphone-product1"

What I've noticed is that the URL above in quotes is missing the category. It's strange because the category appears in the URL in the browser:

http://www.smashingcases.co.uk/personalised-cases/configurable-iphone-product1

This is the first time I've attempted to build a configurable product so it could be something really simple but I can't for the life of me figure out what this string error is and why it's showing a URL with no category?

I've also tried making configurable products in different categories (but using the same attribute set) and I still have the same problem..

Could it be something to do with the attribute set up?

I'm using Magento 1.8 Milano theme.

Answer (score 1):

If that is all that's appearing on the screen then it seems very likely that somewhere within your code there is a `var_dump` that is outputting the product url. I would search the `app/design/` folder for var_dump, since I can't think of a legitimate use (outside of debugging) for it within a theme. There is likely something along the lines of `var_dump($_product->getUrl())`. There are lots of templates that it may occur in so it's hard to guess. Possibly `catalog/product/view.phtml`, but if you are only seeing it for configurable products it could just as easily be in `catalog/product/view/type/configurable.phtml`.

If you don't find any calls to `var_dump` in your design folder then you can also give `app/code/` a try (there are hundreds of places within here that this could be put if somebody has modified the core files).